# Could it be related to proguard? -- Mysterious "NullPonterException" when querying the datastore, with "missing" classes

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

Im developing a simple app to save data to the google app engine's datastore, then to call the datastore and list all entities.

While I am able to store the data in the datastore, I am not able to "query" the datastore.

When I try to build my query, I get the error:
"java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread."

This occurs on this line, no matter where I put it:

```
Query query = new Query("myStoredBean");
```

Note: I do verify that the datastore connection is open and valid prior to calling the above line of code.

Additionally, my logcat is reporting some odd issues in addition to the nullpointerexception and I have no idea how to resolve them:

```
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/io/protocol/ProtocolMessage;' failed
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$Transaction; (2168)
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$Transaction;' failed
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$Transaction', referenced from method com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseDatastoreServiceImpl.a
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2597 (Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$Transaction;) in Lcom/google/appengine/api/datastore/BaseDatastoreServiceImpl;
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/io/protocol/ProtocolMessage;' failed
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$Transaction; (2168)
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$Transaction;' failed
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/io/protocol/ProtocolMessage;' failed
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$PutRequest; (2168)
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$PutRequest;' failed
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$PutRequest', referenced from method com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.a
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2568 (Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$PutRequest;) in Lcom/google/appengine/api/datastore/AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl;
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/io/protocol/ProtocolMessage;' failed
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$PutRequest; (2168)
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$PutRequest;' failed
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/io/protocol/ProtocolMessage;' failed
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/io/protocol/ProtocolMessage;)
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/io/protocol/ProtocolMessage;' failed
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$DeleteRequest; (2168)
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/apphosting/api/DatastorePb$DeleteRequest;' failed
10-01 18:11:38.884  32537-32537/com.myApp.MyModule E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.apphosting.api.DatastorePb$DeleteRequest', referenced from method com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$1.a
```

Any idea how to resolve this?  I am using android studio with the latest app engine apis

Also, I have a core app breaking error that appears after the above, the line referenced is when I am initializing the "Query" object:

```
10-03 10:25:17.844  16385-16385/com.myapp.myModule E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.myModule, PID: 16385
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myModule/com.myapp.myModule.MainActivityWithSwipeableTabs}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.myapp.myModule.MainActivityWithSwipeableTabs.onCreate(SourceFile:66)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2541)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have also tried to locate the "order and export" feature of android studio, which I believe is now essentially located in the project structure section.  I do not know if anything in there would affect this error...

Comment: I think you must debug your code using a debugger for such exceptions and check where your code is having a logical errors.

Comment: When I debug my app, there is no logic error that I see.  It's literally that one line, no matter where it is placed, that causes the issue.  For the google app engine settings, I verified that the settings are correct by being able to post a new entity to the datastore, however I cannot query that same datastore.  That is why it is so odd.  I really appreciate your response though.

Comment: does this work if you turn proguard off in build.gradle

Comment: I cant turn proguard off because it is telling me I have more than the maximum number of classes allowed in my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an app like this working at one point.  Below is the API method from my Endpoint class to query the datastore.

```
     @Api(name = "myendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "domain.com", ownerName =                    "domain.com.com", packagePath = "myPackage"))
 public class MyEndpoint {

    /**
     * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
      * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
 *
 * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
 * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
@ApiMethod(name = "listStuff")
public CollectionResponse<Stuff> listStuff(
        @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
        @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

    EntityManager mgr = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    List<Stuff> execute = null;

    try {
        mgr = getEntityManager();
        Query query = mgr
                .createQuery("select from Stuff as Stuff");
        if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
            cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
            query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
        }

        if (limit != null) {
            query.setFirstResult(0);
            query.setMaxResults(limit);
        }

        execute = (List<Stuff>) query.getResultList();
        cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

        // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
        // for lazy fetch.
        for (Stuff obj : execute)
            ;
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }

    return CollectionResponse.<Stuff> builder().setItems(execute)
            .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
}
```

And I called the method from an AsyncTask with this code.

```
Myendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Myendpoint.Builder(
                AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
                null);
        endpointBuilder =     CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(endpointBuilder).setApplicationName(MainActivity.APPLICATION_NAME);

        endpoint = endpointBuilder.build();

        try {
             result = endpoint.listStuff().execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            // SynchKey = 0;
            // result = null;
        }

        return result;
```

Comment: neat!  Im looking into this code now and will try to sort out the issue on my end

Comment: quick question - the function "getEntityManager()" is giving me the error "cannot resolve method".  Is there a replacement of some kind that you're aware of? I just dont know how to resolve this.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine-java/LYySmvqdbO8/YCV5qgY01VgJ),

`You MUST run the application as a Web Application to be able to activate the App Engine environment with the Datastore that you need for JDO.`

Can you try that to see if it works?

Comment: Ok.  The web application is already installed on google app engine, it is actively running.  I am not using JDO, instead I am using simple data types accepted by the datastore such as "String" types.  This negates the need for JDO objects and keeps the web app simple.  Meanwhile, I am creating an android application that accesses the google app engine.  It successfully is able to store the objects, but cannot "query' them, based on the error messages above.  Thanks for the link though, it was interesting.

Comment: Could it be related to proguard?